# IronPython binding works but throws binding-errors

Tags: wpf, binding, ironpython

When i use IronPython together with WPF-Binding, it throws some binding errors on startup. For example:

[image: Binding Error]

I try to get rid of the errors with the help of `@clrtype returns, accepts` but this does not help. Did I some thing else wrong?

P.S. the binding works, but i want to eleminate the errors.

**EDIT**

Is it possible, that binding in wpf and IronPython only works when binding strings?

**EDIT 2**

If the view models are writting in c# and the rest in IronPython + WPF, every thing seems to work fine too. So the problem must be in the type detection of wpf in combination with IronPython.

**EDIT 3**

Some more information can be found here: https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues/1234

Thank you.